# Implement Key Vault in .NetCore and convert the values to a model in Startup.cs .NetCore application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I have implemented the KeyVault in my .NetCore application. In the Startup.cs, I can get the values using:

`var key1Value = Configuration["Key1"];`

I want to read all the KeyVault values at once and convert it into a Class model values. So that model can be passed to all the services.

My requirement is not to write the Configuration["Key"] in the application, but to pass the model in the services using Dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

Azure key vault configuration provider gives an option of reading configuration values into an array for binding to a POCO array.

In general the configuration keys allow : as a separator. But azure key vault keys do not support colons. You can use double dashes instead --.

Check out the "bind an array to a class" section in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#bind-an-array-to-a-class).